# rosmake ccny_rgbd_tools errors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Thank you so much for providing this valuable open-source package on ccny_rgbd! ! It goes well when I followed the installing procedure: http://wiki.ros.org/ccny_rgbd_tools.

However, it encountered some rosmake errors as the following:

```
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdtools.dir/src/rgbd_frame.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lili/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ccny_rgbd_tools/lib_rgbdtools/rgbdtools_git/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdtools.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lili/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ccny_rgbd_tools/lib_rgbdtools/rgbdtools_git/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lili/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ccny_rgbd_tools/lib_rgbdtools/rgbdtools_git/build'
```

Could anyone provide some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182959/rosmake-ccny_rgbd_tools-errors/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try setting the branch in github to `fuerte` and download that package.

Also remove the existing libg2o from the system software

and

do `rosmake --pre-clean ccny_rgbd`

With these two steps it might work.

**EDIT 1:**

Can you please try with the package from this link

https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools/releases/tag/0.1.1

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-07-03**:
It doesn't work. Still thanks a lot! Have you successfully compiled?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-03**:
@Lili Meng, Yeah I have a compiled version.

Please look at the edit 1 in the answer. If it does not work, then I ll try to provide a link to the version which I was able to compile.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-06**:
did the package from the link in the answer work for you ? @Lili Meng